Issue with including a JPEG-data-structure into to PDF-code as an XObject
In a java program, I want to insert at coding level a JPEG image (which already exists in the java-code/program as a BufferedImage) into a PDF-file.
Since the PDF-viewer (XChange-Editor) does not show the JPEG within the created PDF-File and
Acrobat Reader at least claims an issue with the PDF file (unfortunately without given any information about the nature of the error) there must be something wrong with the PDF-file ("itself", I would say).
Concerned Files:

The source-JPEG-file is ATH_Logo_Pythagoras_241225b.jpg.
The created PDF-file is ATH_PDF-JPEG-Test_241227a.pdf (note: this contains a yellow rectagle just o be sure that anything is drawn in the PDF. The JPEG should be drawn on top of this rectangle; To keep the contents of the page human-readable I apply the only a Filter for the XObject "\XO01" which contains the JPEG part).
Test-extract from the created PDF-File: ATH_PDF-JPEG-Test_241227a_jpgextract.jpg
Re-written JPEG List in order to check if the reading/writing-process of the JPEG is valid: ATH_Logo_Pythagoras_241225b.jpg_rewrite.jpg

If I extract the JPEG code from ATH_PDF-JPEG-Test_241227a.pdf (simply by copying the PDF-file and stripping everything in front of the start of the XObject-stream (line 93, zero-based position: 1317) and everything behind the corresponding "endstream" (pos 7355) I get the file ATH_PDF-JPEG-Test_241227a_jpgextract.jpg.
QUESTION(s):
Since this JPEG file is shown as expected  (e.g, by means of IrfanView) , I think that the the byte-sequence between position 1317 and 7355 in the target-PDF should represent at least a correct JPEG-data structure.
Therefore I have the following Questions

Is the assumption correct, that the byte-sequence in an PDF-XObject stream is identical  to the byte-sequence wihin a "pure" JPEG-file ?
I declared JPXDecode as the Filter for the XObject stream. Is this false? (if so, what else should I do?)
Are there any issues with the XObject dictionary (XObject "/XO01", starting as object nr. 8 from pos. 1169)?

ADDITIONAL NOTES

Apart from stackoverflow my source of information is PDFSPEC

The question concerns the pure PDF-code. It is not the goal to use (i.e. no external applications or libraries (except the java(8)-standard-libraries)

The code is written by an own java code of a larger application, which produces a PDF-file from the scratch.

Within this java-code, I read the source-JPEG-File ATH_Logo_Pythagoras_241225b.jpg (from a local directory) with javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(...) into a BufferedImage. Later in the code this BufferedImage is written with ImageIO.write(imageBuffer, "jpg", outputStream) ; into an ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream which is written with outstream.write(outputStream.toByteArray()) to the PrintStream outstream of the target-PDF-File.

For test-purposes, in the same code I did read and immediately rewrite the source-JPEG ATH_Logo_Pythagoras_241225b.jpg to ATH_Logo_Pythagoras_241225b.jpg_rewrite.jpg JPEG-file. Both files have the same content what means, that reading / writing shpuld actually not be the issue!?. The code for this operation is
          String srcflnm = "ATH_Logo_Pythagoras_241225b.jpg" ;
          BufferedImage image  = ImageIO.read(new File(srcflnm)) ;
          String outflnm  = srcflnm + "_new.jpg" ;
          ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream  = new ByteArrayOutputStream() ;
          ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", outputStream ) ;
          PrintStream outstream   = new PrintStream(outflnm) ;
          outstream.write(outputStream.toByteArray()) ;
          outstream.close() ;    




Running the PDF file through a debug build of Ghostscript I get WARNING: Invalid JPX header, box_len=0xffd8ffe0 and then 'Error: JPXDecode: Unsupported enumCS 0' So this is a JPEG 2000 image, not a JPEG. The JPX encoded image has an enumCS of 0, and that isn't valid in PDF (the other error may mean there is another problem causing this). It may be valid in general for a JPX image (only have the draft spec to hand) but GS at least thinks it isn't valid for PDF, which only supports a subset of JPX. ISO-32000-2 says 'baseline' JPX + CIELab, and CMYK spaces (enumCS 19 and 12 respectively).

Also, GS complains that the image dictionary has a /Name key whose value is not a name object. Yeah just checked the PDF 2.0 specification and the /Name key in an image dictionary takes a name object, not a string object, as a value. I think tha'ts me misleading you previously, sorry about that.

OK so you haven't set a /ColorSpace entry for the image, so Ghostscript tries to treat it as a JPX image (because, crazily, we are allowed to inherit the colour space from JPX image data), and looks to see if the JPX data has a colour space. Since it isn't a JPX image, that fails, hence the error. You also have not set the number of bits per component. If I add '/ColorSpace /DeviceRGB /BitsPerComponent 8' to the dictionary then fix the offsets in the xref, both Ghostscript and Acrobat open the file. I'd be pretty certain that the Acrobat error is due to the missing (required!) key/value pairs.

Thank's again for your support.
I admit that I need to understand the difference between JPEG and JPEG 2000 (will try to the next days). I saw the JPEG2000 in one other question but since "ImageIO.getReaderFormatNames()" of java provided only the "jpg" format, I used this one to read from the filesystem. As said, I use JDK1.8 , which dastes back to the year 2014, whereas the PDF-spec which I refer to is from 2008. Thus I assumed, that the java-JPEG reader would "encapsulate" the java2000 format. I think I am heading for a long way....

I omitted /ColorSpace and BitsPerCompomnent due to the PDF17-Spec, section 7.4.9, pg. 36 and 37. Now I need to find our how I get those information fro mthe JPEG (as long as they are not constant).
I try agai with your proposals.
I need to say: acctually I am programming for engineering purposes. The implementation of Images (PNG, JPEG) is only to be able to add our company-logo onto the PDF-pages ;-) )

I added as adviced "/ColorSpace /DeviceRGB /BitsPerComponent 8", changed the /Name to "/ATH_Logo_Pythagoras_241225b1.jpg" and updated the xref (object no. 9 to "0000007415 00000 n " and startxref to 7435. Unfortunately no success :-( .
Ad least, now the image seems to be "present" in the PDF beacuse there is now and image listet in the list cof contents in PDFCchange_Editor. Further investigation is required.

You don't need to worry about JPX (JPEG2000) if you're going to use regular JPEG images, it's just that the debug message confused me briefly. It is due to the fact that JPEG2000 (as you noted above) permits the colour space and bits per component to be read from the JPX header information. But that is not the case for regular JPEG, in this case those key/value pairs are required. The information is in the JFIF file (the container for JPEG image data) I just can't remember how to get it offhand. Allowing JPX filters to omit it is just annoying for implementors :-(

Hmm I had t update all the xref entries after the image, because they were all wrong when I modified the image dictionary. But after that it worked. Hang on, I'll post my file on DropBox.

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/lamgymqz1fj8hnd6oudxv/ath1.pdf?rlkey=ijbbn9fnxbarjg1mhks9bkbms&st=j2p8b777&dl=0
Should be the file I modified, which opens OK in Acrobat

@KenS thank you very much! Since there was a hint to stop commenting and change to chat (what I cannot do due to my poor reputation) i will better stop here before I even get downvoted.

Thanks! The problem is solved!
Using /Filter/JPXDecode and omitting BitsPerBItplane and ColorDevice was wrong.
Instead, as proposed by K J, "/BitsPerComponent 8/ColorSpace/DeviceRGB/Filter/DCTDecode" should have been used.
(moreover I realized that the PDF1.7-spec claims in Table 6 ("PDF 1.5") whereas my PDF declared itself to be PDF1.4!).
Concenring the questions I conclude

Concerning the questions I conclude
1: The JPEG-byte sequence is NOT identical to the byte sequence of the JPXDecode-Filter (However DCTDecode matches)
2: see above: Instead JPXDecode the filter DCTDecode should have been used
3: The XObject dictionary hat an issue: Instead a String a Name object should have been assigned to the "/Name" key.
(moreover I realized that the PDF1.7-spec claims in Table 6 ("PDF 1.5") whereas my PDF declared itself to be PDF1.4!).
For the moment, the state is fine for me. Thanks to the comments!

(Concerning the source file:
This was originally a vector graphics in PDF [https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/vnym2bxk71ogywr86zu4p/ATH_Logo_Pythagoras_241225b.pdf?rlkey=g3gfvg6nqtzdinykgpzcw3deq&st=vwadp75q&dl=0][ATH_Logo_Pythagoras_241225b.pdf], created by a small java-program written for this purpose. I just used this JPG since I had it at hand.)
